# File creation time do not match when using os.stat()

Tags: python, macos

I need to access the **date of creation** of a file using Python.
As suggested in many posts, I am using `os.stat(filename)` to get such information.
However, the result I get is different from the one I expect.
Here an example:

```
import os, time
f = 'untitled.ipynb' # Created 30 March 2016 at 15:45
fileStats = os.stat(f)
time.ctime(fileStats.st_ctime)
```

The result is :

```
'Mon May  2 16:04:27 2016'
```

Which is incorrect, if I look for it using "Get Info" (in OSX), I get:

```
"Created: 30 March 2016 at 15:45"
```

Does anyone experience the same error?

Do you have any solution to suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

accordint to the documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html:
since you are using OSX, what you need is `st_birthtime` instead of `st_ctime`

> `st_ctime` - platform dependent; time of most recent metadata change on Unix, or the time of creation on Windows.
>
> On other Unix systems (such as FreeBSD), the following attributes may be available (but may be only filled out if root tries to use them):
>
> `st_birthtime` - time of file creation

Comment: And for the relevant Python 3 docs to `st_ctime` see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result

Comment: You answered too fast.. I need to wait 5 mins!